# what is the difference between GtkImage and GdkPixbuf？

Tags: gtk, gtk3

I want to insert an image to a GTKTextView. Should I use GtkImage or GdkPixbuf? there is no information about GdkPixbuf in Devhelp.

Comment: In that case you could/should search for information online ;-) e.g.: https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/ / https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/stable/gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.html#gdk-pixbuf-The-GdkPixbuf-Structure.description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gtk.Image is the GUI widget which allows you to "see" the image. That is display it. GdkPixbuf is a library for loading the image for processing (scaling, viewing etc.)

When you want to insert a widget into GtkTextView, use Gtk.Image.
The Python API for GdkPixbuf is here : https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/#GdkPixbuf-2.0
C Version : https://developer.gnome.org/gdk-pixbuf/